# attempting to reference a deleted function for atomic c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, atomic

I have a piece of code that use to work for Visual Studio 2013. Now that I'm trying to build the same code in Visual Studio 2017 it complains. Here is the code I'm trying to do.

```
#include <array>
#include <atomic>

int main()
{

    using TrdRobotStateArray = std::array<std::atomic<double>, 6>;
    TrdRobotStateArray mCurrentPose = { 0.3 };
    printf("%0.3f", mCurrentPose[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

With this, I get this error:

```
error C2280: 'std::atomic<double>::atomic(const std::atomic<double> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

I didn't write this code, and I'm trying to read into atomic variables. But I'm still not quite sure what is going on with the error. An explanation about atomics would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**update**:

Here are all the errors and warnings that came with this code. So it would help others in the future.

```
1>AtomicTest.cpp
1>AtomicTest.cpp(13): error C4839: non-standard use of class 
'std::atomic<double>' as an argument to a variadic function
1>AtomicTest.cpp(13): note: the constructor and destructor will not be 
called; a bitwise copy of the class will be passed as the argument
1>AtomicTest.cpp(11): note: see declaration of 'std::atomic<double>'
1>AtomicTest.cpp(13): error C2280: 'std::atomic<double>::atomic(const 
std::atomic<double> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\atomic(689): 
note: see declaration of 'std::atomic<double>::atomic'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\atomic(689): 
note: 'std::atomic<double>::atomic(const std::atomic<double> &)': function 
was explicitly deleted
1>AtomicTest.cpp(13): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%0.3f' 
requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 1 has type 
'std::atomic<double>'
1>Done building project "AtomicTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: Wait a second... actually, the first error message you should get for this code is `error C4839: non-standard use of class 'std::atomic<double>' as an argument to a variadic function`. How do you invoke the compiler?

Comment: P.S.: I think the improved error message was added to a recent version of Visual C++ 2017. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp-conformance-improvements-2017. You may want to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Yes, I do get that error too but it disappeared as soon as I applied Jodocus fix. Should I worry about that?

Comment: You mean you were getting that error message all along and chose not only to completely ignore it but also to not add it to your question? Why?

Comment: I thought the two were related

Comment: Please post *all* error messages and warnings next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load the value explicitely in order to compile it:

```
printf("%0.3d", mCurrentPose[0].load());
```

Otherwise, it will try to copy the atomic variable itself for printf() which clearly is not the intent.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. For education purposes. Why does `mCurrentPose[0]` call the copy constructor? What is the benefit of using atomic objects?

Comment: btw, `%f` is used to print float values, and `mCurrentPose[0]` is not a float.

Answer (score 2):

Atomic variables are not **CopyConstructible**.

This is a requirement of the C++ standard, so VisualStudio 2017 is correct.